# C# - Compile a batch file programatically

Tags: c#, file, batch-file

Can i programatically compile a batch file form c#.
Meaning that I give the location of the file and some C# Library compiles the file and gives the output

Can anyone tell me the library for C# that can help me write a small intepreter for C#

Comment: a batch file to execute instructions.I am new to batch files..donno if you are asking abt specific files

Comment: Batch files aren't compiled. They're interpreted by cmd.exe (or command.com on older versions of Windows and in DOS).

Comment: Assuming the batch file is a 'command' batch file you can run it from c#, no need to compile, just look into System.Diagnostics.Process

Comment: If you *really wanted*, you could write your own batch interpreter :)

Comment: @rene..how do i know if it has errors...considering my fikle has errors.?

Comment: @richard..maybe this is what i want to do

Comment: @richard u have any idea how i can do this in C#

Comment: @abbas Give this a shot: http://www.antlr2.org/doc/csharp-runtime.html

Answer (score 3):

Batch files in windows do not get compiled. They get executed by a command processor.

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to execute a batch file from within a C# program.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume this is just a regular windows batch file, you could run it like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start('myfile.bat');
```

That will return a `Process` object.  From there you can get the output stream from the process and read whatever text the batch file writes to the console.